# word-wrap for a url within a table works in chrome and safari, not in firefox

Tags: html, css

I'd like to wrap long URLs within a table:

```
table, td { border: 1px solid black; }
.fullwidth { width: 100%; }
a {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

<table class="fullwidth">
  <tr><td>
    <a href="">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y8bwx7r3/

It's working in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox - any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a display-setting to the CSS rule. Either `display: block;`, or if that doesn't fit, `display: inline-block;` - Firefox seems to treat the default display as `inline` which doesn't work with `word-wrap` and the others.